# Matlab - strange characters on output

Tags: bash, matlab

I run my Matlab scripts from bash in the following way:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r "matlabfun()" &> log
```

The resulting log file starts and ends with a strange character sequence that in `less` appears as: `ESC[?1hESC=`. Do you know what this is caused by?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your error. From [this](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php) table I would assume, that Matlab forces the cursor to be in the application.

I have now idea where else it should be in a bash session, maybe it is a leftover from the graphical version or other platforms. You can just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks! However, do you know how to get rid of it?

Comment: No, but maybe you could construct a workaround using the Matlab's `diary` function.

Answer (score 0):

Do not have the chance to verify it myself, but [this website](http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/nix/general/gnl01-WorkingEnvironment/ar01s27.html) suggests that it is because bash tries to help you.

The solution is to set the `TERM` to invalid entry:

```
TERM=vt444
```

Comment: I've tried running `TERM=vt444 matlab ...` but unfortunately it doesn't help.